# How can I fix this import error on Python 3.8 - PyCharm

Tags: python, macos, keras, pycharm

Here is the error when I try to run the program:

```
File "/Users/kids/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .keras import activations
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.keras'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

And, this is the line that it is saying that has a issue:

```
from .keras import activations
```

Comment: Please use code blocks to format your code and error messages - it makes them easier to read

Comment: Always show the full error traceback.

Comment: Yes I have. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks that the error is at the dot (.) before keras name. Try:

```
from keras import activations
```

Comment: No sorry it does not work. Someone told me to add the dot and before that I was having much more errors, but after I added the dot It fixed most of them.

Comment: @AzanHaider If you had not found solution yet I just got another idea that using just 
```from . import activations``` might do the trick.